# Problemas DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Dado que no se podrá informar un bien con una fecha posterior a la fecha actual que se está declarando (en este caso, no se podría indicar una fecha posterior al 31/12/21), se solicita que el calendario se muestre abierto en diciembre/2021. Adicionalmente, se sugiere bloquear las fechas posteriores a la fecha actual que se está declarando para evitar errores en la carga por el usuario (en este caso, se bloquearían las fechas posteriores al 31/12/21). Mi pregunta es quiero poner mismo año en el calendario porque siempre el calendario aparece el año anterior?

El código es REACT

registerLocale("es", es);

export const Datepicker = (props) => {

return (
<DatePicker

```
  style={{ width: '100%' }}

  className="form-control"

  locale="es"

  peekNextMonth

  showYearDropdown

  showMonthDropdown

  disabledKeyboardNavigation

  dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"

  {...props }
/>
```

);
};

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Te hace falta detallar bien tu pregunta, incluyendo el código con el que estés trabajando.

Comment: Incluye ese código en la pregunta Martin, por favor.